# Ajax Datatables Rails - Query not working for show-method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, jquery-datatables-rails

Let's start with the database-model:

```
# => ProductSelection.rb
has_many :products, -> { uniq }, through: :product_variants

# => Product.rb
has_many :product_informations
belongs_to :product_configuration
belongs_to :product_class
```

Using plain Ruby on Rails, we collected the `products` to show inside the `product_selection#show`-method like so:

```
@products = ProductSelection.find(params[:id]).products.includes(:product_informations, :product_class, :product_configuration)
```

and generated a table like so:

```
  = table(@products).as(:products).default do |product|
    = product.name
    = product.product_configuration.name
    = product.product_class.name
    = product.state
    = link_to product_product_selection_path(@product_selection, product_id: product.id), method: :delete
```

Now we want to use Datatables instead of plain Ruby on Rails.

We are using the [Ajax-Datatables-Rails-Gem](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails.). We would like all columns to be sortable and searchable in the end.
Unfortunately we do not come past the query to retrieve the `Products` belonging to the `ProductSelection` in question.

This is the query we tried so far:

```
 def get_raw_records
    ProductSelection.find(params[:id]).products.includes(:product_informations, :product_class, :product_configuration).references(:product_information, :product_class, :product_configuration).distinct
 end


 def data
    records.map do |record|
      [
        record.name,
        record.product_configuration.name,
        record.product_class.name,
        record.state,
        record.id
      ]
    end
  end
```

The error that pops up:

```
> undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass
```

When adding in sortable/searchable columns, the error is the following instead:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn at /product_selections/fetch_table_data_show.json
=====================================================================

> ERROR:  column products.name does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "products"."id", products.name
```

with the configuration like so:

```
  def sortable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    @sortable_columns ||= %w(Product.name ProductConfiguration.name ProductClass.name Product.state)
  end

  def searchable_columns
    # Declare strings in this format: ModelName.column_name
    @searchable_columns ||= %w(Product.name ProductConfiguration.name ProductClass.name Product.state)
  end
```

I think the problem is with the different models right here. I assume Datatables-Rails expects a model of `ProductSelection` but instead is prompted with a `Product`. Any help would be highly appreciated!
If anything is missing, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having another look at this, we figured the problem was that `Product.name` wasn't a valid ActiveRecord-construct. Instead it was a helper method defined somewhere down the road.

Since the gem tries to find records through the column-names, this error occurred.

We solved it by removing the column in question. Other approaches would be to:

1. Store the data in a separate column, instead of using a helper.
2. Implementing the helpers behavior in javascript so that we can pass
       it as a callback to datatables.